# How to check for an event and remove it?

Tags: c#, itext

Is there a way to check to see if a PageEvent has already been added to a PdfWriter object?  If so, can you also remove said PageEvent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Java version of iText, there's a method `getPageEvent()` available in `PdfWriter`. There should be a `GetPageEvent()` or `PageEvent` in iTextSharp that you can use to find out if there is a page event present.

To remove an existing page event, you need to set the page event to `null`. Adding an extra page event won't replace the existing page event, but add an extra event that will be triggered along with the original event(s).

Comment: Thank you very much.  That was exactly the issue with removing the previous event.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good example for adding total page number to every page.
http://www.mazsoft.com/blog/post/2008/04/30/Code-sample-for-using-iTextSharp-PDF-library.aspx

check this http://geekswithblogs.net/guilhermecardoso/archive/2010/10/19/itextsharp---use-header-with-events.aspx

Have a look at Page Events, in particular onStartPage and/or onEndPage to determine if you have to change the margins of the document. http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=204

.

Please note that these examples are for the Java version, but the conversion to iTextSharp should be straightforward.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, does it?